# resize png image using rmagick without losing quality

Tags: imagemagick, image-resizing, rmagick

I need to resize an 200*200 image to 60*60 in rmagick without losing image quality. Currently I am doing following for a png image

```
img = Magick::Image.from_blob(params[:file].read)[0]
  img.write(RootPath  + params[:dir_str] + "/#{filename}") do
    self.quality=100;
    #      self.compression = Magick::ZipCompression
  end
```

I am losing sharpness in the resulting image. I want to be able to resize by losing the least amount of image quality. 
I tried to set it's quality and different compressions, but all of them seems not works fine.
all resulting image are still looks being removed a layer of colors and the word character are losing sharpness

anyone could give me some instructions for resizing png images?

Comment: PNG is a lossless format, so any quality loss is either a result of imagemagik's algorithms or just the fact that you're cutting the resolution in third and that changes things.

Comment: Really? You're resizing a picture from 200x200 = 40,000 down to 60x60 = 3,600 - that is, less than a tenth of the resolution - and you're surprised that you lose image quality?

Comment: @ChrisLatta You're correct; I fail at resolution-math and divided the dimensions instead of the pixel count. A tenth is far more than a third.

Comment: well, the art designing told me the result image is losing the quality. and he gave me one expected 60*60 image which is resized by using the PS. I checked the image and compared with the generated image, it did look quite different. so i tried all compress types what the rmagick provided, but all of the result image were losing the sharpness

Comment: if it caused by imagemagik's algorithms, are there any gem tools could provide a better solution for image resizing ?

Comment: I've tried different filter for method resize. and it seems 'Magick::SincFilter' this one could provide a better view. well, it still not as good as the expected image. any other method could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're resizing a picture from 200x200 = 40,000 down to 60x60 = 3,600 - that is, less than a tenth of the resolution - and you're surprised that you lose image quality? Think of it this way - could you take a 16x16 image and resize it to 5x5 with no loss of quality? That is about the same as you are trying to do here.

If what you are saying you want to do was actually possible, then every picture could be reduced to one pixel with no loss of quality.

With the art designer's 60x60 image being better quality than yours, it depends on the original size of the image that the art designer is working from. For example, if the art designer was working from an 800x800 image and provided your 200x200 image from that, then also reduced the original 800x800 image to 60x60 in PS then that 60x60 image will be better quailty than the one you have. This is because your 60x60 image has gone throuogh two losses of quality: one to go to 200x200 and the second to go from 200x200 to 60x60. Necessarily this will be worse than the image resized from the original.

Comment: no,no, the art designer gave me two images, one is the original 200*200 and the other is the expected 60*60. my job is to let server get the upload image from client, save it and provide a 60*60 preview to user. I compared the uploaded image with the orignal 200*200, (well, used the same img.write method to store it in server) both of them are looks quite similar no much differences could be found by eyes, but when checked the generated 60*60 image, it really not good, the word on the 200*200 image were almost be unrecognized (the expected 60*60 not like this),

Comment: so i want to find a better way to let the image have a better view.

Comment: Remember that quality will drop off at an exponential rate, not a linear rate. For example, a picture with half the quality/resolution of 200x200 isn't 100x100, it is 141x141. 100x100 is one quarter of the resolution of 200x200 and the exponential decrease in resolution means that by the time you get to 60x60 it is less than one tenth the resolution, and hence quality. I think you are getting a 60x60 image from your art designer that is produced differently from the process you are using - i.e. your 60x60 has undergone two resizings and losses in quality whereas the other one has only one.

Comment: well i think you're right. hopefully i could convince my boss, anyway i prepared a most clearly preview for him. And the method i've used is : 
    img=imgl.resize(width, height,Magick::SincFilter)
    img.write(new_image_name) do
      self.compression = Magick::ZipSCompression 
      self.quality=100;
    end

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the png to a vector image, resize the vector to 60x60 then convert the vector to png. Almost lossless.